# FusionChart Multi-series dataset number prefix

Tags: dataset, number-formatting, fusioncharts

Is it possible to each dataset to have it's own numberPrefix?

```
<graph caption='Product Sales' numberPrefix='$' >
```

However this puts the same dollar sign for every dataset. What i want is to show for product A , totals in EUR / GBP / USD, and for product B EUR / GBP / ZAR etc.

This is what i got :

```
<dataset  seriesName='EUR' numberPrefix='EUR'  color='AFD8F8' >
    <set  value='153.23'  />
</dataset>
<dataset  seriesName='USD' numberPrefix='USD'  color='F6BD0F' >
    <set  value='36925'  />
    <set  value='3546'  />
</dataset>
<dataset  seriesName='ZAR' numberPrefix='ZAR'  color='8BBA00' >
    <set  value='158623'  />
</dataset>
```

This does not show appropriate prefix to the numbers shown ontop to each column. Is this possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FusionCharts does not support "numberPrefix" attribute in dataset level. It is a chart level attribute and is applied globally in the entire chart when used.

You cannot show multiple dataset with different "numberPrefix" as of now.